# Fill ion-content with a 100% height div

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I am working with ionic and am trying to fill the entire ion-content with a div. Within this div, I want to center a text horizontally & vertically.

I have achieved something, but this seems to only work within the browser, as soon as I upload the APK to my android device, it doesn't work anymore. I believe this is due to this line (please see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/batmat/pen/PPKdyj) I made) :

`height: calc(100vh - 120px);`

I wish I could use something else to get the full height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I would try including the `-webkit` prefix. Both `calc()` and viewport units should work in Android.

```
height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 120px);
height: calc(100vh - 120px);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. It's like the device ignore this line of CSS. (to reproduce on codepen, just delete the "height" line)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found the solution, I am not sure why I did not find that during my previous searches. So I am basically using that :

```
myDiv {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/bokboki2002/pen/rVyMgE